# How to get the following Electric Diagram in Latex?

Tags: circuitikz

[image]

I do not know how to use circuitikz package and I was wondering how to input the following diagram in Latex

The code I tried so far:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}[
    ]
    \draw (0,0) coordinate(start) to [short, i=$i$] ++(1,0) coordinate(a)
    to [R=$R_3$] ++(3,0) --++(0,-1) coordinate(c)
    -- ++(-1,0) to[R, l_=$R_4$] ++(0,-2) -- ++(1,0) coordinate(d)
    (c) --  ++(1,0) to[R=$R_4$] ++(0,-2) -- (d)
    -- ++(0,-1) to [R=$R_7$] ++(-3,0) coordinate(e)
    (a|-e) -- (start|-e)
    to [capacitor, l=$370 sent$, invert] (start)
    ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe you can at least show what you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, welcome. Please read the `circuitikz` manual, especially the first tutorial, and try to draw your first circuit. If you find a specific problem, post it with your code. As it is, this is a "please do it for me" question, which is off-topic here. Your other option is to use a graphical program, like for example [`xcircuit`](http://opencircuitdesign.com/xcircuit/), and import the diagram in LaTeX, so you do not need to learn Ti*k*Z and `circuitikz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Sorry but your sketch is not readable.
- Element units is seems to be in your native language, which I don't speak, so I only guess, what units you like to have.
- You not provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a complete small document with your circuit, so I don't know what settings for it you use.
- I guess that you after the following:

[image]

At drawing above diagram i use `siunitx` syntax adopted to `circuitikz` pictures, i.e.: `=value<units>`. For example `[C=370<\nano\farad>]`. Complete MWE is

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}  % <---

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw   (0,0)   coordinate(start) 
                to [short, i=$I_1$] ++ (1,0)    
                to [R=2<\ohm>]      ++ (3,0)    coordinate (a) 
                to [short, -*]      ++ (0,-1)   coordinate (b)
                to [short, i_=$I_1-I_2$]    ++ (-1.2,0)
                to [R=3<\ohm>]      ++ (0,-2)
                to [short, -*]      ++ (1.2,0)  coordinate (c)
        (b)     to [short, i=$I_2$]         ++ (+1.2,0)
                to [L=2<\henry>]    ++ (0,-2) -- (c)
                -- ++ (0,-1)
                to [L=1<\henry>]    ++ (-3,0)
                -- ++ (-1,0)
                to [C=370<\nano\farad>] (start)
        ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation, I greatly appreciate it.